# How to interpolate a string containing pug code within a pug file?

Tags: javascript, express, pug, string-interpolation

I need to interpolate a string containing some pug formatted code within a pug file.

What I have tested:

```
- var text = "i.home.icon"

div= text
div !{text}
div #{text}
div ${${text}}
div {{text}}
div {text}
div \#{text}
div \{text}
div ${text}
div
    #{text}
```

What I want :

```
<div><i class="home icon"><i></div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Tag interpolation exists within pug, but not strings representing tags with classes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a [mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html).  [Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/graham-sportsmgmt/pen/roKqqJ) that shows it working in a live example.

```
mixin tagCreator(def)
  - var tagArray = def.split('.');
  - var tag= tagArray[0];
  - tagArray.shift();
  - var classes = tagArray.join(' ');
  |<#{tag} class='#{classes}'>
  if block
    block
  |</#{tag}>

+tagCreator('one')
+tagCreator('two.three.four') Two
```

The code above creates this HTML:

```
<one class=""></one>
<two class="three four">Two</two>
```

A quick explanation of what it does, line by line:

1. Splits the period-delimited string into an array
2. Stores the tag name separately
3. Removes the first element in the array
4. Joins the rest of the array into a space-delimited string suitable for `class=""` output
5. Use a pipe delimiter to output the [plain text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html) tag with classes
6. Output any content added to the tag, if it exists
7. Close the tag, again using plain text